# Single-tap for text selection doesn't work in UIWebView when content is small

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with some lorem ipsum:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];

    [webView loadHTMLString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis urna risus, vitae sagittis justo. Aenean et justo elementum augue adipiscing tincidunt eget nec urna. Cras lorem nunc, commodo at ullamcorper ut, eleifend nec metus. Phasellus lectus elit, mattis non fermentum quis, elementum vel augue." baseURL:nil];

    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [container addSubview:webView];
    [self setView:container];
}
```

I can single-tap-and-hold to select the text, as expected:

[image]

But when I remove the last couple sentences of lorem ipsum (such that the content fits inside the webview's frame, and the vertical scrollbar is no longer induced), then I can no longer single-tap-and-hold to select text:

[image]

(I can still select the text, however, via **double**-tap-and-hold, though this has the slightly different behavior of selecting the entire paragraph by default.)

I'm struggling to (a) understand the current behavior and/or (b) fix it so single-tap-and-hold always selects the text.

Comment: Well, this might not be germane, but I can't help noticing that you are calling `loadHTMLString:` with something that is *not* an HTML string. Try giving it valid HTML: at the very least wrap that puppy in `<p>`, `<body>`, and `<html>` tags. It might matter or it might not, but at least let's eliminate it.

Comment: @matt That didn't seem to the do the trick. BUT I think I may have stumbled upon the answer in the process of testing your suggestion. I'll post a self-answer in a sec after a bit more investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have stumbled upon the solution while randomly fiddling with variables:

The text is only selectable (via single-tap-and-hold) if either (a) the height of the webview is >= 100 or (b)  the height of the webview's content is >= 100.

100 seems to be the magic number here: if I bump the height from 100 to 101, then text selection works as expected.

**EDIT**

In a separate example, the magic number was 104. So there's some height *n*, below which text section stops working normally, but I haven't discovered the pattern behind *n*.

Comment: +1 for making up such a wild and crazy answer. I mean, you don't expect anyone to *believe* this, do you? :))))

Comment: Oh, and don't forget that in a couple of days you can accept your own answer to signal that you've solved the problem.

Comment: @matt Will do. Oh and your HTML suggestion led me to this answer, because the natural margin/padding of `body` and `p` bumped the content height over 100 :)